# Conditional flow in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have script for SQL plus, which I use to create user and get arguments for username and password.

I want the script to do more things when it runs on oracle 12c, but I'm trying to avoid writing different script for each DB version.

I have the following function to return version major number:

```
create or replace function get_version return integer AS
oracle_version integer;
begin
  select(substr(version,1,instr(version,'.')-1) into oracle_version 
  from PRODUCT_COMPONENT_VERSION
  where product like 'Oracle%';  
  return oracle_version;
end;
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
if get_version >= 12 then
  alter session set ...;
end if;
create user &1 identified by &2 ... ;
/
grant create session to &1;
grant create table to &1;
```

Any idea how to do it?

Thanks

**EDIT**

it works like this:

```
declare v integer;
begin
  set v:=get_version;
  if v>= 12 then
    execute immediate 'alter session ....'
  end if;
end;
end;
create user &1 identified by &2 ... ;
```

Comment: Look up conditional compilation. It is for situations exactly like this.